# Wrong value of state displayed after refreshing a page from useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a problem with my page that fetch data from a server and displays it for the user. I am using the hook `useEffect` for it.
My problem is that the first time I visit a page the correct data are displayed (so from `/home` I go to `/product1` I get correct information). But after manually refreshing my page `/product1` even though the server is getting the correct information again, my state object of my page will not update again. Is there a way to fix this? Code below:

```
const [productInfo, setProductInfo] = useState({
    saleStarted : null,
    quantityPerSize : []
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchdata = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const query = new db.Query('Products');
      query.equalTo('productId', params.productId);
      await query.find()
        .then(async (response) => {
          setdata(response[0].attributes);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(err);
          console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
    if(isInitialized){
      fetchdata();
    }
  }, [isInitialized]); 


  useEffect(() => {
    const saleStartedInfo = async() => {
      const options = {
        link : url + params.contractId,
      }
      try{
        let started = await db.find(options)
        console.log(started); //returns true
        setProductInfo({...productInfo, saleStarted : started});
      }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    const quantitySize = async() => {
      let _quantityBySize = [];
      for(let k = 0 ;k<data.numberOfSize;k++) {
        let options = {
          address : url + params.contractId,
        }
        try{
          let quantitySize = await db.find(options);
          _quantityBySize.push(quantitySize)
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
      console.log(_quantityBySize); // let's say returns [5,4,10] if product has 3 size
      setContractInfo({...contractInfo, quantityPerSize : _quantityBySize})
    }
    if(isInitialized && data){
      saleStartedInfo();
      quantityMinted();
    }
  }, [data])
```

So after rendering this page the first time it will show sale started, and quantity `5`, `4` and `10`. After refresh it will show sale not started and `quantity === []` (empty array)

Comment: Is it possible that your fetch may be incorrect and that it's not correctly fetching the quantities?

Comment: Hi no because if I log the result before using setState I have the expected results.

Comment: So, I fixed it by splitting in two distincs parts my state instead of using:
```
const [productInfo, setProductInfo] = useState({
    saleStarted : null,
    quantityPerSize : []
  })
```
to 
```
const [saleStarted, setSaleStarted] = useState(false);
const [quantityPerSize, setQuantityPerSize] = useState([]);
```
I think setState methods were "interfering" one to another so that state was not updating both correctly. Since 1 time my my saleStarted would update but not quantityPerSize and vice versa. If anyone can confirm that would be great.